# Delete and select on table impact when done simultaneously

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g

I am having table ABC and using in procedures with Delete action at starting and select action at end. (Delete with no where clause)

Now if a process A invokes the procedure and it is at select on table ABC, then at same time another process B invokes the procedure which reached to Delete on ABC without any where clause.

So my question is, would process A can find the data as Delete with no where clause is happening at same time.

Literally, is synchronization would be there among tables.

Comment: My understanding is, If same processes from the same session, process A will not return any data unless it runs before B. In case they are from different sessions, process A will return data as long as no commit statement issued by B

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest you read about Oracle multi-versioning and ACID transactions

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18283_01/server.112/e16508/consist.htm

https://en.wikipedia.org/?title=ACID

Things that happen in a session within a transaction are not available to another session. This continues until a commit is issued. You have your own version until a commit or rollback is issued.

Oracle starts a transaction by default unlike some other database servers. Other database servers also have their own defaults and different implementations of ACID.